# How to have Single App mode for a web app on an iPad using Apple Configurator 2?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, fullscreen, web-app

I would like to have a web app to be the only thing you can use with an iPad. I managed to make the website (a simple HTML file with lots of integrated JS) open full screen when added to the home screen as a starter, so there are no browser controls, just the app and a black panel displaying battery status and clock. On the other hand I can use the Apple Configurator 2 to lock the iPad to a single app like Safari but in Safari I have all the browser controls.

What I would like to achieve is locking the iPad to use the web app full screen. However, I cannot do this, because in the Apple Configurator I can only choose from the apps installed on the MacBook it is executed on. Since the web app is not a proper app but just a starter on the iPad's home screen, it is not listed amongst the MacBook's apps.

Is there a possibility to have the iPad locked into the web app in full screen, without browser controls?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is possible and it is even easier then using Apple Configurator 2. You just need to go to settings-> general->accessibility->Guided Access.

Then when you are in the webapp click three times the home button and draw where the you user can not interact anymore. They can not leave the app, or use the home and power button.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Any update to this method?

It's 2020 and just trying understand if something has changed since.